# Spark: RuntimeException: java.lang.String is not a valid external type for schema of date

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This works fine:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, DateType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq( ("2018-01-01", "2018-01-31", 80)
            , ("2018-01-07","2018-01-10", 10)
            , ("2018-01-07","2018-01-31", 10)
            , ("2018-01-11","2018-01-31", 5)
            , ("2018-01-25","2018-01-27", 5)
            , ("2018-02-02","2018-02-23", 100)
            ).toDF("sd","ed","coins")

val schema = List(("sd", "date"), ("ed", "date"), ("coins", "integer"))
val newColumns = schema.map(c => col(c._1).cast(c._2))
val newDF = df.select(newColumns:_*)
newDF.show(false)
```

and is a work-around for this below issue I present:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, DateType};

val someData = Seq(
                     Row("2018-01-01","2018-01-31", 80)
                   , Row("2018-01-07","2018-01-10", 10)
                   , Row("2018-01-07","2018-01-31", 10)
                   , Row("2018-01-11","2018-01-31", 5)
                   , Row("2018-01-25","2018-01-27", 5)
                   , Row("2018-02-02","2018-02-23", 100)
                  )

val someSchema = List(
  StructField("sd", DateType, true),
  StructField("ed", DateType, true),
  StructField("coins", IntegerType, true),
)

val dfA = spark.createDataFrame(
  spark.sparkContext.parallelize(someData),
  StructType(someSchema)
)

dfA.show(false)
```

generates an error as follows:

```
Caused by: RuntimeException: java.lang.String is not a valid external type for schema of date
```

I am aware of the int, bigint problem and indicate a workaround for date in the first snippet, but I cannot seem to use the Date Type - I would like to know how on the 2nd snippet, continuing in this vein.

Comment: interesting... I wonder what's the use case though? if reading from csv you can specify date format / timestamp format, and presumably this shouldn't happen...

Comment: Just preparing for the databricks exam and revising. I cannot find the correct approach, more academic admittedly, but one would expect that the approach should work ideally

Comment: may be we just need to assume that in general source is always from disk, stream and leave it at that, but curious myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much experimentation, `trying df.rdd.map{...` and `asIntanceOf[Date]`, no joy.

My first approach as stated above is the way to go:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, DateType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq( ("2018-01-01", "2018-01-31", 80)
            , ("2018-01-07","2018-01-10", 10)
            , ("2018-01-07","2018-01-31", 10)
            , ("2018-01-11","2018-01-31", 5)
            , ("2018-01-25","2018-01-27", 5)
            , ("2018-02-02","2018-02-23", 100)
            ).toDF("sd","ed","coins")

val schema = List(("sd", "date"), ("ed", "date"), ("coins", "integer"))
val newColumns = schema.map(c => col(c._1).cast(c._2))
val newDF = df.select(newColumns:_*)
newDF.show(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first instance your dates are strings and you subsequently cast them to a date with `newColumns`. With the second instance you are trying to insert a string value into date data type -- its not going to work. They need to be strings first, (because thats what they are) and then cast them to a date like you did in the first instance. Also, you have a trailing comma is `someSchema`  and I don't see Row being imported either.

Comment: more observations than answer. i get that all and am looking for the elegant way.

Comment: running in a notebook

Comment: I was trying to tell you whats happening under the hood. if you look at the execution plan its exactly the same. If you want answer just take what you have `dfA.select(col("sd").cast('date'), col("ed").cast('date'), col('"coins"))`. it doesn't have to be a condensed code to be elegant.

Comment: the extra , does not cause a run-time issue, odd but that is how it is

Answer (score 0):

In the second instance, why not just have `java.sql.Date` objects instead of `String` date objects?

Working solution:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, DateType}

import java.sql.Date

val someData = Seq(
                     Row(Date.valueOf("2018-01-01"),Date.valueOf("2018-01-31"), 80)
                   , Row(Date.valueOf("2018-01-07"),Date.valueOf("2018-01-10"), 10)
                   , Row(Date.valueOf("2018-01-07"),Date.valueOf("2018-01-31"), 10)
                   , Row(Date.valueOf("2018-01-11"),Date.valueOf("2018-01-31"), 5)
                   , Row(Date.valueOf("2018-01-25"),Date.valueOf("2018-01-27"), 5)
                   , Row(Date.valueOf("2018-02-02"),Date.valueOf("2018-02-23"), 100)
                  )

val someSchema = List(
  StructField("sd", DateType, true),
  StructField("ed", DateType, true),
  StructField("coins", IntegerType, true),
)

val dfA = spark.createDataFrame(
  spark.sparkContext.parallelize(someData),
  StructType(someSchema)
)

dfA.show(false)
```